# headless mode not working (python%selenuim)

Tags: python, selenium

**I'm trying to make a spam dm Instagram bot
I just get this error**

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element`

I just want it to work in headless mode and here is my code
when I use a non-headless mode it just works I don't really know why so please help me

there is more code but im just importing the error line code which is the first

`driver.find_element_by_xpath`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep

def instsspamdm():
    user = input("Enter the username: ")
    password = input("Enter tha password: ")
    target = input("Target: ")
    mess = input("Target message: ")
    sleepTime = int(input("Sleep[sec]: "))
    delay = float(input("Delay[sec]: "))
    autoMode = input("Auto Mode[y/n]: ")
   
    if autoMode == "y":
        options = Options()
        options.headless = True
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = options)
        driver.get("https://instagram.com")
        sleep(sleepTime)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/label/input").send_keys(user)  # Account Username
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[2]/div/label/input") \
            .send_keys(password)  # Account Password
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[3]/button") \
        y = 1

        while True:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/textarea")\
                .send_keys(mess)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/button")\
                .click()
            x = "Done Spam: "
            print(x, y)
            y += 1
            sleep(delay)
```

Comment: _...Unable to locate element..._ Which element?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the screen size when using headless.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
driver.get("https://instagram.com")
```

Else it will use the default, which I believe is (800x400)

Comment: Thank you but that didn't help too, and i don't think that the screen size might be the problem because it can't locate the element path `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try to use "ChromeOptions" and also input "desired_capabilities" when creating the webdriver. I don't recall how I arrived at this, but it has been working for me.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PathToChromeDriverEXE, options=options, desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())
```

If this applies to your issue I'll research why I arrived at this solution.

Comment: Thank you, but it's still not working for me apparently the problem is that it cant locate the element path `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element`